# Heap corruption when constructing AABB tree with OPENMP

Tags: openmp, cgal, heap-corruption, aabb

I have a for loop containing approximately 1,000,000 iterations of calling *AABBTree.all_intersections()* method. Thus, I use *#pragma omp parallel for*  to speed up the program. However, I got an error as "A heap has been corrupted". The cpp file is roughly like the following:

```
Polyhedron polyhedron;
Facet_tree m_facet_tree(faces(m_polyhedron).first, faces(m_polyhedron).second, m_polyhedon);

#pragma omp parallel for
for (int i = 0; i<100; ++i){
    Plane plane = Plane(1, 0, 0, 0);

    // Compute intersections
    typedef std::vector<Facet_tree::Object_and_primitive_id> Intersections;
    Intersections intersections;
    m_facet_tree.all_intersections(plane, std::back_inserter(intersections));
}
```

Finally, The program will break here:

```
    ~Handle()
    {
    if ( PTR && (--PTR->count == 0))
        delete PTR;
    }
```

What are the possible reasons that cause this problem? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You should provide a [mre] in order to get some useful help. Many informations are missing on your classes. But  most likely, some of your function calls are not thread safe. For instance, when you insert something in your heap, there is global var updated without atomic access, that leads to races between threads  and when this happens the heap condition is no longer respected.

Comment: You shouldn't have an issue if you use `CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel`. I think you are using `CGAL::Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel` that is not yet thread safe.

Comment: @sloriot You are right! I am using epeck which is not thread-safe yet. I switched to epick and it just worked.

Comment: @AlainMerigot Sorry for the incomplete example. I will try to make it reproducible next time.